# Regular Expressions with part of a URI

Tags: regex

I'm not very familiar with regular expressions.

I'm trying to create a regular expression that will match the text between the first group of two forwards slashes. It's easiest just to show an example.

```
Search Texts:
/index
/index/
/index/foo/
/index/foo/bar/
All of those should return just "index"
```

Another example:

```
Search Texts:
/page.php
/page.php/foo?bar=1
Should return just "page.php" for both of those
```

Thanks alot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one for javascript or php preg_match: `^\/([^\/]*)`

The pattern matches only of if there is a slash at the beginning and then matches everything that is not a slash.